# 4D Region Plot with multiple inequalities

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, regions

I am trying to draw a polytope with 4 variables. These 4 variables are probabilities so their lower bounds are all 0 and upper bounds are all 1.

Here are the inequalities that define the polytope:
$$\alpha\geq 2\beta, \quad 2\sigma\geq\gamma,\quad 2\alpha\geq3\gamma,\quad3\sigma\geq2\beta,\quad\alpha+\beta+\sigma+\gamma=1$$

I think what I need to do is draw a 3D plot whose axes are $\alpha,\beta,\sigma$ and a color coding for $\gamma$. Can anyone help me with drawing this plot please? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using color as the fourth dimension has severe limitations for regions that are solid in that you can only see the color of the surface of the region. While [`Opacity`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Opacity.html) could be used to see "into" the solid region, the colors would be muddled together and you would not be able to appreciate the fourth dimension.

```
ineq = α >= 2 β && 2 σ >= γ && 2 α >= 3 γ && 
     3 σ >= 2 β /. γ -> 1 - (α + β + σ) // Simplify;
```

**EDIT:** You can use [`Manipulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) to peal back the boundaries to see the inner values

**EDIT 2:** The color range for the plot needs to be adjusted to the range of `γ`.

Determining the range of `γ`

```
#[{1 - (α + β + σ), α >= 2 β, 
    2 σ >= γ, 2 α >= 3 γ, 
    3 σ >= 2 β,
    α + β + σ + γ == 1, 0 <= α <= 1, 
    0 <= β <= 1, 0 <= σ <= 1}, {α, β, σ}, 
   Reals] & /@ {MinValue, MaxValue}
```

[image]

Rescaling for `-3/2 <= γ <= 1/3`

```
Manipulate[Module[
  {ineq = α >= 2 β && 2 σ >= γ && 2 α >= 3 γ && 
       3 σ >= 2 β /. γ -> 1 - (α + β + σ) //
     Simplify},
  Legended[
   RegionPlot3D[
    ineq && αlb < α < αub && βlb < β < βub && σlb < σ < σub,
    {α, 0, 1}, {β, 0, 1}, {σ, 0, 1},
    AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {α, β, σ}),
    PlotPoints -> 100,
    ColorFunction ->
     Function[{α, β, σ}, ColorData["Rainbow"][
       Rescale[1 - (α + β + σ), {-3/2, 1/3}]]]],
   BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {-3/2, 1/3}}]]],
 {{αlb, 0}, 0, 0.98, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{αub, 1}, αlb + 0.01, 1, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{βlb, 0}, 0, 0.48, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{βub, 0.5}, βlb + 0.01, 0.5, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{σlb, 0}, 0, 0.98, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{σub, 1}, σlb + 0.01, 1, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 SynchronousUpdating -> False]
```

[image]

**EDIT 3:** I forgot to restrict `γ` to interval `{0, 1}`. This significantly reduces the region of interest.

```
#[{1 - (α + β + σ), α >= 2 β, 
    2 σ >= γ, 2 α >= 3 γ, 
    3 σ >= 2 β, α + β + σ + γ == 1, 
    0 <= α <= 1, 0 <= β <= 1, 0 <= σ <= 1, 
    0 <= γ <= 1}, {α, β, σ}, Reals] & /@ {MinValue,
   MaxValue}
```

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{ineq = (α >= 2 β && 2 σ >= γ && 
        2 α >= 3 γ && 3 σ >= 2 β && 
        0 <= α <= 1 && 0 <= β <= 1 && 0 <= σ <= 1 && 
        0 <= γ <= 1) /. γ -> 
       1 - (α + β + σ) // Simplify}, 
  Legended[RegionPlot3D[
    ineq && αlb < α < αub && βlb < β < βub && σlb < σ < σub, 
     {α, 0, 1}, {β, 0, 1}, {σ, 0, 1}, 
    AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {α, β, σ}), 
    PlotPoints -> 100, 
    ColorFunction -> 
     Function[{α, β, σ}, 
      ColorData["Rainbow"][
       Rescale[1 - (α + β + σ), {0, 1/3}]]]], 
   BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0, 1/3}}]]], {{αlb, 0}, 0, 0.98, 0.01, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{αub, 1}, αlb + 0.01, 1, 0.01, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{βlb, 0}, 0, 0.28, 0.01, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{βub, 0.3}, βlb + 0.01, 0.3, 0.01, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{σlb, 0}, 0, 0.98, 0.01, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{σub, 1}, σlb + 0.01, 1, 0.01, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, SynchronousUpdating -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Really love this plot

Comment: In this case there was a rescaling of gamma; is it possible to make a colored picture like this if we would not have the alfa+beta+sigma+gamma=1?

Comment: @RafaelWagner - A constraint on `gamma` in terms of `{alpha, beta, gamma}` is what enables reducing the inequalities to a 3D implicit region in `{alpha, beta, gamma}`. Without a defined 3D region, coloring is not possible.